# Upgrading project to Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode7, xcode8

I am upgrading my project to Xcode 8 and I have literally hundreds of errors that say I have something incorrect that is correct. After retyping the same code from an error-ridden line or cleaning my project, the error message goes away until Compile Time. I converted my whole project to Swift 3.0 multiple times and am constantly cleaning the project, so why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: This error message is when you type Swift 3 code in a Swift 2 compiler, like when using Xcode 7. Be careful to not have Xcode 7 opened when using Xcode 8, it can create mess like that. Quit Xcode, delete the contents of the derived data folder of your project then open it in Xcode 8 again.

Comment: How do I see the DerivedData for the project? @EricAya

Answer (score 0):

The converter is not perfect and can only do so much for you. You will need to manually fix these errors yourself. This is made a lot easier if you have a copy of the documentation for both versions and can then check the differences between the versions.

Another tip. The Xcode 8 release documentation contains all the changes to the swift syntax and in most cases is all you will need. You can view a copy for Xcode 8 here: [Xcode 8 release docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html)

Comment: I understand this but I have manually typed in corrections as well and it shows as correct until compile-time. It recognizes correct code as error-ridden.